# MYSQL Arranging/Reorganizing Database Via buttons

Tags: javascript, mysql

Is there any way to arrange the order of items in the database via buttons/javascript?

i.e. I have the first table in my database and I want to be able to arrange it freely.

```
| id | name |   change to   | id | name |
-------------     ---->     -------------
| 1  | Iris |               | 1  | Lens |
| 2  | Pupil|               | 2  | Iris |
| 3  | Lens |               | 3  | Pupil|
```

how do I move them using a button like an arrow up/down?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Swapping rows in database is not very simple. You'll have to add a new column containing sequence number, every time you'll swap, you'll have to update the numbers in database.

Comment: so meaning I will have an empty row in the db as container? @Shaharyar

Comment: @Nerdicon no it means you should have another _column_ in your table indicating the current sequence number of each item, which you can then use in an ORDER BY query to sort the items. Then your user interface will need to allow the user to easily change the sequence number.

Comment: @ADyson Thats what I said. I think you meant to mention the OP :)

Comment: @Shaharyar lol sorry so I did, got confused!

Comment: The user int is just simple, just a textbox showing the database entries and an up and down arrow beside it. So if up arrow is clicked, it should swap the contents but I have no idea how to do it. @ADyson

Comment: well it would need to maintain its own list of sequence numbers, and swap them round. Then it needs to send them to the database, via ajax and then a server-side language e.g. php. Have you got anything like that set up in your environment?

Comment: Well I use symfony 2.3 which is a php framework but it's still confusing for me to be dealing with database. @ADyson

Comment: I suggest you read a tutorial on connecting to mysql from PHP then, and how to write SQL queries. If that's completely new to you then there's really too much to cover in a single SO question

Comment: By connecting you mean like persisting and removing data from db? That I can do, but anything other than that is out of the question. @ADyson

Comment: so you know how to make select, insert and update queries? And you know how to invoke this from php?

Comment: No, I don't know SQL statements yet. ( T-T ) @ADyson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments:

I suggest you go and read up on the basics of SQL, make an attempt to write some code to solve your problem and then ask a more specific question. We can't really teach you SQL in a single question on here.

Here's a clue though: For what you want to do in terms of changing the sequence number, UPDATE statements will be what you want. a single statement can operate on multiple rows simultaneously. so say if you move an item (Item A) from position 10 to position 2, you could do the following steps:

- update Item A's sequence number to 2
- update all items with a sequence number between 2 and 9 (excluding item A, whose sequence is now 2), such that you increase the sequence number of each item by 1.

You can do this using 2 SQL UPDATE statements, one for each of the points above. Probably they'd look something like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET Sequence = 2 
WHERE ItemID = 'A'

UPDATE MyTable 
SET Sequence = Sequence + 1 
WHERE ItemID <> 'A' AND Sequence >=2 AND Sequence <= 9
```

If you want to update multiple items' sequence in one call to the DB, look into transactions, which can ensure all the statements are applied, or all rolled back if there's an error, to ensure consistency of your data.

Note that the sequence number is different from the ID which uniquely identifies the row (and should never change). You'll need to add this extra column to your table. In the example above I've used ItemID as a string as the identifier to avoid confusion with the integer sequence number, but in reality your identifier is probably going to be a number or GUID of some sort.

Finally, to get your items out in sequence order you can run the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY Sequence ASC
```

Comment: @Nerdicon no problem. if the answer has helped you please upvote and/or mark as accepted answer. thanks :-)

Comment: @Nerdicon did this answer help you?

Comment: Yes it did, although it turns out that symfony's _way_ of UPDATE and INSERT INTO is different, but it did help me so I guess it's accepted